# split array element in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have an array in Perl where each element contains the a username and password which is seperated by a space. I.e.

```
@listOfUser = {testuser password1, testuser2 password2, testuser3 password3};
```

I want to loop through the array and split each element into two strings. For example, I want to take the first element in the array and assign it to a variable called username and the respective password to a variable called passwd.

Essentially my question is that I want to split an array element into two strings!

---

I am using perl. Let's speak generally. I have an array which contains several elements.

Each element is in the format: `sometext mypassword`
Basically each element contains a username followed by a space and then a password.

I want to be able to grab each element and split the element so that

```
my $username = sometext
my $password = password
```

I will then pass the two strings into a function using a foreach loop

Comment: `Can't locate object method "testuser" via package "password1" (perhaps you forgot to load "password1"?) at - line 1.` — what code are you really using?

Comment: You will get better responses if you post working code (or, at least, code that compiles).

Answer (score 6):

```
for my $elem (@listOfUser) {
    my ($username, $password) = split " ",$elem;
    # do something with $username and $password
}
```

Comment: @sanster, If this helped (is correct), you should mark it correct, not just thank. On StackOverflow marking something correct is the best form of flattery. Although as you learn more Perl, I personally think Sinan's answer is a little more Perl-ish, though ennuikiller's certainly is fine.

Comment: @Joel, Sinan's answer is definitely preferred, however for a novice (which the op apparently is considering the question) I think my answer is a bit more easily understood.

Comment: agree wholeheartedly. Just encouraging the op to mark something correct, not just say thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my @users = (
    'testuser password1',
    'testuser2 password2',
    'testuser3 password3',
);

@users = map { my ($u, $p) = split; { user => $u, pass => $p } } @users;

print Dump \@users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answers already given: why use an array? A hash would IMHO be a better solution:

```
my %user_password = (
    user1 => 'pass1',
    user2 => 'pass2',
    ....
);

for my $user ( keys %user_password ) {
    print "username: $user, password: $user_password{$user}\n";
}
```

Paul

Comment: Presumably because it is already in that form, from a file or a database or some other construct. Otherwise a hash is def the way to go.